# Can I obtain Monero testnet coins without mining?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-gui, testnet

Is there an easy way to obtain free Monero **testnet** coins without needing to start mining on testnet?

The goal is to just make 2 testnet wallet addresses, either from the CLI or the GUI, and send some coins back and forth, to get familiar with the way Monero works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you pop into /r/monero on reddit, or on Slack/IRC #monero, you will find people who would be happy to send you testnet coins.

Alternatively, it is rather satisfying to mine your own.  The difficulty on the testnet is quite low, so odds are high that you will see returns in the first day or two.  I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is possible. Someone on Reddit, made a [public testnet wallet](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5s59x3/public_testnet_wallet/), from which you could transfer some moneroj to your own address(es), to experiment with (e.g. cold signing, etcetera).

First create your own testnet wallet(s), and then you'll need create another wallet to restore from the mnemonic seed posted in the Reddit article. From that one, you can transfer some moneroj to your own testnet wallet. Please be courteous, and don't drain the wallet.

Note that testnet addresses start with `9`, while mainnet addresses start with `4`.

Answer (score 0):

There's also an [Open Monero](https://github.com/moneroexamples/openmonero) for testnet website at http://139.162.32.245:81/ (I think hosted by mWo12) where you can take some testnet moneroj, by logging in with the default private login key.

Comment: Seems to be back up.

Comment: my bad maybe I caught it in a minor outage.