# Monero Javascript Library

Tags: testnet, javascript

It is my first time working with Monero, since it is a coin based on blockchain I guess it follows similar principles than BTC and ETH.

1. Is there a javascript library like bitcore or web3 to interact with it?
2. Is there a testnet?
3. Is there a test faucett?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

1. Monero JavaScript/node.js - https://github.com/PsychicCat/monero-nodejs
2. Monero private testnet setup - https://github.com/moneroexamples/private-testnet
3. Test faucet - see [Can I obtain Monero testnet coins without mining?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/can-i-obtain-monero-testnet-coins-without-mining)